# cant' install sublimemaven plugin successfully

Tags: maven, sublimetext2

I follow this https://coderwall.com/p/etesrq to install the sublimemaven plugin for my sublime2.
All steps seems ok, but I can't get the 'Maven' menu item in 'Tools->Build System'.
I have added the 
"m2_home": "F:/jill/job/software/apache-maven-3.0.4",
add
"maven_menu_commands":
by following https://github.com/nlloyd/SublimeMaven.
and restart sublime2 several times.
but still can't get it.
Could some body help?
Thanks

Comment: I am currently facing the same problem.

Comment: SublimeMaven development appears to have been abandoned for the last three years and does not appear to support Sublime Text 3 (see: https://github.com/nlloyd/SublimeMaven)

Comment: I am seeing the same problem!

Answer (score 2):

[Nick Lloyd's `SublimeMaven` plug-in](https://github.com/nlloyd/SublimeMaven) installed nicely for me on [**Sublime Text 3**](https://www.sublimetext.com/3) but showed build commands only in the [Command Palette](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/command_palette.html) (`CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`P`).

Only after I added [Andres Koetter's configuration file](https://gist.github.com/akottr/6164036) to the `Packages/User` directory of my portable `SUBLIME_TEXT_3/Data/` dir (or `~/.config/sublime-text-3/` for some) I found a `Maven` build option in the `Tools > Build` menu. This new option enables Sublime Text 3's [build system run commands](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems/configuration.html#running-build-systems) for Maven builds, that is:

- Build (`CTRL`+`B`) : run default build configuration
- Build with ... (`CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`B`) : select `mvn` [goals](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html), [profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html), [command-line options](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.1.0/maven-embedder/cli.html), etc.

Comment: I had to update the config file's `working_dir` entry to `"$folder"` for this to work (as per the [documentation](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/build_systems.html#variables)). Otherwise, mvn is invoked from the folder of the current file which is usually wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I find that I don't have "maven" in "tools" -> "build system" either, but using cmd + shift + p , then type in "maven", I can see several commands, one of them is "maven: Run...", I use this command when I need to specify one. Commonly, other default maven commands could satisfy your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a working directory tip that I found on this URL: https://gist.github.com/4ndrej/5162986

Once I finished instructions provided by user2951392, I got working Maven menu on sublime text 3. Then I tried to build some projects, but for each one of them I got an error like this: "...there is no pom.xml file on directory E:\sublime...".

So, just change the following content on Maven.sublime-build file:

- old: "$file_path"
- new: "${project_path:${folder}}"

With this final change I got my sublime text 3 and Maven 3+ working fine.

Cheers!